# attach a link on linkedin and facebook not showing logo on my asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, meta-tags

I have a asp.net website with a logo. When I go on facebook or linked in and type in my website it does not show up with the logo. I did some research and added the meta tag below on my website but it did nothing. Is there a way to let social sites know what my logo is thanks for any help.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="My LOGO Image URL" />
```

Thank you all for your help. I guess it is physically impossible to use your logo on as the thumbnail when you attach a link on facebook or linked in or any other social site. maybe they will allow you to do this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your header and it should work:

```
<link href='YourIconPath' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
```

The icon needs to be in ICO format for it to work (gif or png do not work).
You can test it in Internet Explorer and see if the correct Icon is displayed in the AdressBar.

You can find additional information here:

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1423-favicon-have-the-icon-of-your-site-in-the-address-bar

Comment: I already have a favicon it loads fine on my site but when I want to share on FB and linkedin it does not work

Comment: What is the format of the favicon ? What are the sizes? Did you try my meta tag ? Sometimes it needs some time to be updated...

Comment: Well maybe LinkedIn and FB do not pull the favicon and if so you can not share your logo automatically.

Comment: this did not work for me <link rel="icon" href="/SiteImages/logo_large_FINAL.png" type='image/x-icon'/>. My Favicon set but nothing on the social sites

Comment: Does not work. Facebook or Linkedin does not even recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

put this in the head

```
     <link href="/path_to_your_icon/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/image/png" />
```

I personally use the link like this:   , like the other answer

```
      <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

but LinkedIn says to style it the first way

Comment: does it matter if its a gif? and Can this go on the site master?

Comment: yes it matters- has to be .ico , or I should say , it has to be called .ico

Comment: then why did you put type="image/image/png"

Comment: Use the syntax <link href='YourIconPath' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/> and it will work. This is the general way of how to define favicons. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I already have a favicon it loads fine on my site but when I want to share on FB and linkedin it does not work

Comment: this did not work for me <link rel="icon" href="/SiteImages/logo_large_FINAL.png" type='image/x-icon'/>. My Favicon set but nothing on the social sites